# Supercapacitor Discharging - Strange Behaviour

Tags: capacitor, supercapacitor

So i have a bank of [Vishay "196 HVC ENYCAP" supercapacitors](https://docs-emea.rs-online.com/webdocs/15ee/0900766b815ee509.pdf) and I am witnessing strange behaviour when discharging them that I cannot explain.

The bank has an equivalent capacitance of 60F. I have charged the bank to 6V (all supcaps in bank are rated for 7V) and placed a 100 ohm resistor across the bank and monitored the fall off in voltage.

The results were as follows:
Voltage after 5 minutes: 2.4V,
Voltage after 10 minutes: 1.16V,
Voltage after 15 minutes: 1.16V,
Voltage after 20 minutes: 1.02V.

Based on the voltage decay formula of Vt=Voe^(-t/RC), the voltage should only have dropped to 4.91V after 20 minutes.

However then after removing the 100 ohm resistor, the voltage immediately recovered to 1.97V. After 15 minutes the voltage had recovered to 3.38V, and after 30 minutes to 4.2V.

I have checked all connections and they are fine.

Is there something I am missing here? Is the voltage expected to drop off as much as it has before recovering over time?

Comment: for one, maybe your calculation of capacitance is just wrong, also caps can recover voltage after "discharged"

Comment: The bank consists of 4 15F supercapacitors placed in parallel for 60F. I have also checked the connections so I am sure I have the capacitance right. Would you say the the level of voltage recovery I have witnessed is a 'normal' level of recovery?

Comment: I have no idea, and since you have not posted a link to a datasheet nobody could check anything about your caps.

Comment: @TRJ94 Are you sure you don't have some hidden wire set to charge them up? The caps may recover, but what you describe is either charging, or your voltmeter has a weak battery?

Comment: No theres no connection to a charging point. I have never had trouble with the voltmeter before, though I may double check this behaviour using a different one

Comment: @PlasmaHH “caps can recover voltage”, I didn’t get that part. I thought the energy stored was cv^2/2... how could it recover?

Comment: Please post a link to the capacitor data sheet.  Some supercapacitors are electrochemical and have battery-like characteristics as you describe.

Comment: Also check the impedance/ESR of the super caps.

Comment: Are you aware that 20 minutes is 1200 seconds?

Comment: A few people have asked for the datasheet. Here it is: https://docs-emea.rs-online.com/webdocs/15ee/0900766b815ee509.pdf The one I have is a 5 cell 7V 15F, with 4 of them in parallel

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast Apparently he his, because his capacitor discharge function checks out for 1200 seconds.

Answer (score 2):

Dielectric absorption typically causes effects like this. The amount of voltage recovery seems excessive. The degree to which this effect occurs depends on the material that the dielectric is made from.

Capacitors are sometimes transported with a short across the terminals to prevent this effect  from causing problems.

Comment: I don't think the dielectric absorption is the actual mystery, rather why they drop so much when trying to draw a smallish load.